# How do I find the highest common number for each group in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

Here is my table example:

```
LETTER  NUMBER
a   1
a   2
a   4
b   1
b   2
b   3
c   1
c   2
c   3
d   1
d   2
d   3
e   1
e   2
e   3
```

The result I want:

```
LETTER  NUMBER
a   2
b   2
c   2
d   2
e   2
```

The highest number that matches an 'a' is 4, while it's 3 for the other letters. However, the highest letter they all have in common is 2. That is why the result table has 2 for the NUMBER.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: GROUP BY (letter) and MAX (number) ..

Comment: @pst: I think you need to read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call your table `l`. Here's a horribly inefficient solution:

```
select l.LETTER, max(l.NUMBER)
from l
where
    (select count(distinct LETTER) from l)
  = (select count(distinct l2.LETTER) from l as l2 where l2.NUMBER = l.NUMBER)
group by l.LETTER;
```

Kind of a mess, huh?

Comment: Agreed. I would be interested in seeing alternate solutions.

Comment: Yes, this works, although I didn't realize the "l" in 1.LETTER was a placeholder for my table's name.

Comment: It's `l.LETTER`, not `1.LETTER` :)